# C++ Returning a child class from within a parent class

Tags: inheritance

So I have two classes like this

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"
class A {
public:
    B getB() {}
};
```

and

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"
class B : public A {

};
```

Error: 'A' base class undefined.

Both need to be declared before the other one so how do I fix this?

If you reorder the code into one file then it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B : public A {

};
class A {
public:
    B getB() {}
};

void main() {
    A a;
    B b = a.getB();
    system("pause");
}
```

But the problem is still there...

Comment: What is the IDE that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Before being used in inheritance, a class should be fully define.
- Before being used in a value (i.e. member, variable, input parameter, return value), a class should be fully defined.

So here you're stuck. The workaround usually done is to return the class by reference/pointer/shared_ptr:

```
// Forward declaration
class B;

class A
{
  public:
   B& GetB();
};

class B : public A
{ /* ... */ }

B& A::GetB() { return a_b_from_somewhere; }
```

But note that you will certainly have to deal with problems of owner ship in that case (i.e. who owns the pointer you return ?)

Comment: Ok thanks, quick question about that function, how can I fix this?

        B& getB() { 
            B a(4);
            return a;
        }

Errors are: 

C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'B &'

C2079 'A::c' uses undefined class 'B'

Comment: Just implement it after `B` declaration. (example updated)

Comment: Thank you I owe you one!